# How interpolate 3D coordinates

Tags: python, r, 3d, interpolation, splines

I have data points in x,y,z format. They form a point cloud of a closed manifold. How can I interpolate them using R-Project or Python? (Like polynomial splines)

Comment: A closed manifold is something topologically equivalent to a sphere? No holes or edges? The usual approach is to triangulate the surface, so first, form your triangles... Have you looked at any 3d visualisation packages for this?

Comment: There are many ways. Not quite sure what you mean with x,y,z format though. If you describe a function f(x,y) = z, and you are fine with x and y having the same number of points, try out the akima package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/akima/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "compact manifold" do you mean a lower dimensional function like a trajectory or a surface that is embedded in 3d? You have several alternatives for the surface-problem in R depending on how "parametric" or "non-parametric" you want to be. Regression splines of various sorts could be applied within the framework of estimating mean f(x,y) and if these values were "tightly" spaced you may get a relatively accurate and simple summary estimate.  There are several non-parametric methods such as found in packages 'locfit', 'akima' and 'mgcv'. (I'm not really sure how I would go about statistically estimating a 1-d manifold in 3-space.)

Edit: But if I did want to see a 3D distribution and get an idea of whether is was a parametric curve or trajectory, I would reach for package:rgl and just plot it in a rotatable 3D frame.

If you are instead trying to form the convex hull (for which the word interpolate is probably the wrong choice), then I know there are 2-d solutions and suspect that searching would find 3-d solutions as well. Constructing the right search strategy will depend on specifics whose absence the 2 comments so far reflects. I'm speculating that attempting to model lower and higher order statistics like the 1st and 99th percentile as a function of (x,y) could be attempted if you wanted to use a regression effort to create boundaries. There is a quantile regression package, 'rq' by Roger Koenker that is well supported.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what the points originally represented. Just having an array of points is generally not enough to derive the original manifold from. You need to know which points go together.

The most common low-level boundary representation ("brep") is a bunch of triangles. This is e.g. what OpenGL and Directx get as input. I've written a Python [software](http://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/software/index.html#stl2pov) that can convert triangular meshes in [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) format to e.g. a PDF image. Maybe you can adapt that to for your purpose. Interpolating a triangle is usually not necessary, but rather trivail to do. Create three new points each halfway between two original point. These three points form an inner triangle, and the rest of the surface forms three triangles. So with this you have transformed one triangle into four triangles.

If the points are control points for spline surface patches (like [NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NURBS), or [Bézier surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface)), you have to know which points together form a patch. Since these are parametric surfaces, once you know the control points, all the points on the surface can be determined. Below is the function for a Bézier surface. The parameters u and v are the the parametric coordinates of the surface. They run from 0 to 1 along two adjecent edges of the patch. The control points are k_ij.

[image: formula of Bézier patch]

The B functions are weight functions for each control point;

[image: weight functions]

Suppose you want to  approximate a Bézier surface by a grid of 10x10 points. To do that you have to evaluate the function **p** for u and v running from 0 to 1 in 10 steps (generating the steps is easily done with `numpy.linspace`).

For each (u,v) pair, **p** returns a 3D point.

If you want to visualise these points, you could use [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) from matplotlib.